# ASP.NET MVC6 without EF

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

is it possible to use MVC6 without using EF?. Wanted to confirm as we have a huge application in .NET 4.0 WebForms which uses a custom BL layer and DB Layer to talk to multiple databases ( SQL Server & PostgreSQL) seamlessly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible. EF is just help you to call database